# Weka UI and API code in Java gives different results

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am new to Weka.

I am trying to run WEKA using API's and have found out that the results from the WEKA GUI does not match to the one produced by the Java code.

I am trying to run a RandomForest Algorithm by providing TrainingSet and Test Set.

Here is the code snippet:

```
            DataSource ds = new DataSource(trainingFile);

            Instances insts = ds.getDataSet();

            insts.setClassIndex(insts.numAttributes() - 1);

            Classifier cl = new RandomForest();
            RandomForest rf = (RandomForest)cl;
       //     rf.setOptions(options);
         //   rf.setNumExecutionSlots(1);
            rf.setNumFeatures(5);
            rf.setSeed(1);
            rf.setNumExecutionSlots(1);                  

            Remove remove = new Remove();
            int[] attrs = WekaCustomisation.convertIntegers(attrList);

            remove.setAttributeIndicesArray(attrs);
            remove.setInvertSelection(true);                

            remove.setInputFormat(insts);
            insts = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(insts, remove);

            insts.setClassIndex(insts.numAttributes() - 1);            


            weka.core.Instances train = new weka.core.Instances(insts, 0, insts.numInstances());          


            cl.buildClassifier(train);

         weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource ds2 = new weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource(testFile);

            weka.core.Instances instsTest = ds2.getDataSet();
            remove.setInputFormat(instsTest);
            instsTest = weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(instsTest, remove);
            instsTest.setClassIndex(instsTest.numAttributes() - 1);                

            Instances testInstances = new Instances(instsTest);
            int numCorrect = 0;

            weka.classifiers.Evaluation eval = new weka.classifiers.Evaluation(train);
            eval.evaluateModel(cl, testInstances);
            System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString());
            out.write(eval.toSummaryString());
            double roc = eval.areaUnderROC(0);
```

The confusion matrix produced by the WEKA GUI and this code differs. What am I missing here.

Comment: How different are the reported numbers?

Comment: The confusion Matrix if I run for the Training set, it is not such a way apart. But still it is not the exact same. If I run the Test set, it is way apart like, 
This is the result for the code:                                    a   b   <-- classified as
 104  47 |   a = X
 120 772 |   b = Y
For Weka UI
a   b   <-- classified as
 104  47 |   a = X
  41 851 |   b = Y

Answer (score 2):

At first check if the parameters and filterings executed in the Weka GUI are the same you are doing in the code. (take a look at the log generated in the GUI)

A second possilibty is the random component that the Random Forest models have in its creation structure (selecting random features in the dataset for each decision tree, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_forest)). So, during the training phase different models are generated to the same train dataset and when you evaluate with the test you get different results.