# Using Weka gives different results between GUI and API implementation

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, classification, weka

I am using Weka to do classification of my dataset. First I did this using the GUI giving me some results (Accurracy, ROC, ...). Now that I'm using the API to implement a small framework around WEKA, I run the exact same configuration yet getting different results.
Let me give you an example:

Config of .ARFF file in GUI:

```
    @relation 'QueryResult-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NominalToString-Clast
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R2-W1000-prune-rate-1.0-N0
 -stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-M1-O-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \",
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToNominal-R2-last
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToBinary-unset-class-temporarily
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NominalToString-Cfirst
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1-W1000000-prune-rate-1.0-C-T-I-N0-L-S
 -stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-M1-stopwords/Users/stopwds.txt-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer 
 -delimiters \" \\r \\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!-/<>[]\\t\\r\\n\"-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R120-1964
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R121-123'
```

As I said, using the API I use same config:

```
@relation 'QueryResult-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NominalToString-Clast
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R2-W1000-prune-rate-1.0-N0
 -stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-M1-O-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer -delimiters \",
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToNominal-R2-last
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToBinary-unset-class-temporarily
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NominalToString-Cfirst
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1-W1000000-prune-rate-1.0-C-T-I-N0-L-S
 -stemmerweka.core.stemmers.NullStemmer-M1-stopwords/Users/stopwds.txt-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.WordTokenizer 
 -delimiters \" \\r \\t.,;:\\\'\\\"()?!-/<>[]\\t\\r\\n\"-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R120-1964
-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove-R121-123'
```

Now when I run the classifier, again with same configurations, I get different output! However, the funny part is when I load the .ARFF file generated from my Java code after running the config and then train the classifier there, I DO get the exact same output as expected/required.

Can please someone explain what I'm doing wrong and why the output is different? I read other posts such as [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872974/weka-ui-and-api-code-in-java-gives-different-results?rq=1) where a similar problem occurred.

--
To clarify, here is the config of my classifier in the GUI:

```
 weka.classifiers.lazy.IBk -K 30 -W 0 -I -A "weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch -A \"weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last\""
```

And this is how it is in my Java code:

```
iBk.setOptions(weka.core.Utils.splitOptions("-K 30 -W 0 -I -A \"weka.core.neighboursearch.LinearNNSearch -A \\\"weka.core.EuclideanDistance -R first-last\\\"\""));
```